# word frequency from file using partial match

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have  a text file like this:

```
tom
and
jerry
went
to
america
and
england
```

I want to get the frequency of each word.

When I tried the following command

```
sort test.txt|uniq -c
```

I got the following output

```
   1 america
   2 and
   1 england
   1 jerry
   1 to
   1 tom
   1 went
```

But I need partial matches too. ie, the word `to` present in the word `tom`. So my expected word count of `to` is 2. 
Is it possible using `unix` commands?

Comment: If your `test.txt` file was created anywhere near an MSWindows machine, preprocess it with `dos2unix test.txt`. And you don't need `cat`, just sort file | uniq -c` works as expected for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    cnt[$1] = 0
    next
}
{
    for (word in cnt) {
        cnt[word] += gsub(word,"&")
    }
}
END {
    for (word in cnt) {
        print word, cnt[word]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
went 1
america 1
to 2
and 3
england 1
jerry 1
tom 1
```

Since you mentioned in a comment about being low on RAM, if you don't have enough RAM to store all unique words from your file in memory at once then do the above in a loop of N (10? 100? 1000?) thousand words at a time, e.g. (bash-like pseudo-code):

```
sort -u file > tmp
for (( i=1; i<=$(wc -l < tmp); i+=10000 )); do
    awk -f tst.awk <(head -n "$i" tmp | tail -n 10000) file
done
```

Comment: ++ I was going to post almost similar answer but with `++cnt[word]` in the `for` loop body. Why do you need `gsub(word,"&")` esp if line has some regex meta characters like `am(erica`?

Comment: @anubhava I started with `if ( index($0,word) ) cnt[word]++` but I changed to the gsub() so that if the sub-word appears twice in a longer word (e.g. "**to**" in "**to**ma**to**") it gets counted twice. I'm taking the OP at his "word" (no pun intended) that they're dealing with word-constituent characters, no re metachars.

Comment: @EdMorton this program fails for some cases. for the text file mentioned in question, its returning only one line for the following command    `sort -u sample.txt > tmp
for (( i=1; i<=$(wc -l < tmp); i+=10 )); do     awk -f tst.awk <(head -n "$i" tmp | tail -n 10) sample.txt; done`

Comment: @EdMorton another issue i am facing is when i pasted the above commands in .sh file . i got the following error when i ran the sh file `frequencyFinder.sh: 11: frequencyFinder.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable`

Comment: I said in my answer that it's "bash-like pseudo-code" so you shouldn't expect to be able to just execute it and have it work out the box, you'll need to think a little bit and then write code **like that** yourself. If you're getting a syntax error when you put it in a file then copy/paste the contents of that file to http://shellcheck.net to help you start debugging it.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `grep` for every unique word of your file :

```
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    count="$(grep -o "$pattern" test.txt | wc -l)" # can't use grep -c as it counts lines
    printf '%s: %d\n' "$pattern" "$count"
done < <(sort test.txt | uniq)
```

Comment: thank you. this command works. if i run this command against a large file around 30gb, will a machine of 8gb ram handle that?

Comment: I don't think memory would be a problem, but the execution time will probably be very long.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for an idea of just HOW long! It will be many orders of magnitude slower than an awk script, for example - on the order of hours vs seconds.

Comment: @EdMorton I considered suggesting OP to use your answer instead of mine as it's obviously way more time-efficient, but wouldn't he risk running into memory problems considering the size of his file and the use of an in-memory map?

Comment: Yes, so I added an option to handle that by looping on some subset of N thousand of the words at a time.

Comment: Ah nice, I hadn't seen your edit. @TweetMan, consider using Ed Norton's answer instead of mine (and if you do, you're welcome to change the accepted answer to his)

Comment: Ed, @Aaron ha. thanks. i will try both methods with a large file. thanks for your time :)

Comment: "Ed Morton"*, sorry about the typo

Comment: @TweetMan: Just an advice that you should have mentioned **a large file around 30gb, on a machine of 8gb ram** in your question so that you could get answers geared towards that.

Answer (score 1):

**Script :**

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r word; do
    count=`grep -o "${word}" file | wc -l`
    echo "${word} : ${count}"
done < file
```

**Output:**

tom : 1
and : 3
jerry : 1
went : 1
to : 2
america : 1
and : 3
england : 1

Comment: You're missing a sort+uniq on the input of the loop, you have two "and : 3" in your output. Also the `IFS=` bit could be removed, since you're reading into a single variable it's going to have the whole line's content anyway

Comment: @Aaron `IFS=` isn't something you add when you need to, it's something you do by default and **remove** (or alter) when you **need** to, just like `-r` from read and quotes around variables.

Comment: I see my comment on IFS was misguided, I expected the result to be the same but it looks like not setting an empty IFS would lead to whitespaces being trimmed. Thanks @EdMorton

Answer (score 1):

Perl was made for things like this, if you've got it:

```
$ perl -e '@lines=<>;for $x(@lines){chomp $x;print 0+grep(/$x/,@lines), " $x\n"}' text_file
1 tom
3 and
1 jerry
1 went
2 to
1 america
3 and
1 england
```

The `<>` in list context reads all the lines at once into the array.

`chomp` gets rid of the ending newline.

The `0+` puts `grep` into scalar context where it evaluates to just the count.

Comment: I see you mentioned 30GB input. Don't do this on that. It reads the entire file into memory!